# Calling an API inside an ASP.net MVC Controller Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I am developing an asp.net mvc web application in which I need to call [OMDB api](http://www.omdbapi.com/) (an api to get Imdb information of a movie). I need to send a simple GET request to the api and get the response(movie details), deserialize the response into an object and pass it to the view. Is this possible without using a reference to an external library? Can anybody give me an example on how to do it inside a controller action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **WebRequest** class

```
using System.Net;

string url = "https://www.service.com?param=movieName";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Reference:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023

Comment: thanks for the answer and it worked well! I used `StreamReader` class to  read the responseStream.